# Version control with a team of non-developers

Tags: git, version-control

At work we have decided to redo our website from scratch since over the years it has been plagued with no version control or dev site, plugin inconsistencies, etc. The team who created the current site were a bunch of designers and a few others with basic wordpress editing skills. Needless to say the site is an awful hack job. I am currently the only developer, but some of the designers & others are still in place. I'm in charge of creating a new workflow that works for everyone. I'm really not keen on teaching git to everyone that will edit this site nor do I trust any of the rest of the team to have control like that.

All that being said, since I am the only developer but we NEED to version the new workflow, what are some suggestions? I suppose I will be the only one creating and editing plugins, etc., but my designers do know how to create their own templates, etc. so they will be editing and adding code.

So the question is: Is there any happy medium that will allow my designers to edit the theme files and push them live without having to teach them version control?

Comment: If you only version control half your project, you're not really reaping the benefits. My recommendation would be to not go down that road. If a user touches code, he or she checks it in.

Comment: There are lots of Git GUIs out there. Maybe one of these would help the more command line-shy: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: Git for non-techies without knowing Git? No, it's impossible. Maybe only SVN in the form of [EasySVN](http://svn-ref.assembla.com/easysvn.html) and git-svn from your side

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Source Tree https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/, no need to learn heavily the command line git, all the non coders need to do is copy their files to your repo, then commit and push if there are no complications that will arise.

The only bad side of this is if there will be merge issues that needs to be resolved, it might mess up the code or you can't proceed pushing your changes